# Calling C# GenericType<T> function library from python

Tags: python, c#, generic-type-argument

I am exporting 3 C# functions to a library to be called from a python script.
Those C# functions are using generic Type as parameters.
So that in my python script I can all them using any value type

Here are the 3 exported C# functions:

```
    public void TestValue_1_Parameter_wTypeT<T>(T value)
    public void TestValue_2_Parameters_Strings(string value, string param2)
    public void TestValue_3_Parameters_wTypeT<T>(string ident, T value)
```

I am able to properly call function 1 with different types for T value without any problem

```
    MyObj.TestValue_1_Parameter_wTypeT("hello world")
    MyObj.TestValue_1_Parameter_wTypeT(2)
    MyObj.TestValue_1_Parameter_wTypeT(24.4)
    MyObj.TestValue_1_Parameter_wTypeT(True)
```

Event the print log of typeof(T) is reporting properly in the C# library

I am also able to call function 2 with 2 string parameters

but I am unable to call function 3.

When doing so:

```
    MyObj.TestValue_3_Parameters_wTypeT("hello world", 2)
```

I have this error:

```
E    TypeError: No method matches given arguments for TestValue_3_Parameters_wTypeT: (<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)
```

It looks like the signature is not found ??
Any idea ?

Comment: just for checking can you call the third function with 2 strings?

Comment: No, in that case I have the following error:    E    TypeError: No method matches given arguments for MyObj.TestValue_2_Parameters_wTypeT: (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)

Comment: I have been told that it might be related to encoding and that I would need to put a #pragma to force an encoding norm to be the same used by python